# AngularJS passing data with services but lost data with a page refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've a problem with passing some data from a controller A to a controller B using a Factory (or a Service) when user hit refresh on browser. I can succesfull set the data from controller A and get the data from controller B, but when I'm in the view of controller B, if I hit refresh, I lost the data and I get an "undefined".
I need to use a $localStorage to resolve, any idea? What's wrong?

The service factory is very simple, I've an object like:

```
var obj = {};
```

then I've two methods:

```
    return{
getObj: function(){return obj;},
setObj: function(data){ obj = data;}
    };
```

My controller A use the setObj, and controller B use getObj. The first time I run it, all works well, but when I'm on the controller B view, I lost the data with a page refresh.

Comment: This is normal behavior. When user clicks refresh - he wants new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, your data will be lost on page-refresh,this is normal. When you refresh the page, the service and controllers associated with your current page reloads, so as a result data gets reset or in your case this object

```
var obj = {};
```

gets reinitialized again.

You can either store in localStorage on in cookie for persistent data, i would suggest you to use localStorage because of size and also because if you use cookies, then for each ajax request, the cookie data will also go, which is not suggested.

Comment: Is it okay to use to $cookies or $localStorage, because that is not secure, anybody can see in resource tab of browser developer tool or I am just confusing ?

Comment: Depends, if you are sending cookies data for each request to server then it it would not be a good approach to use cookies as unwanted cookies data might go for each request, instead using localStorage would be good approach here. And regarding security, you can encrypt cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You never have persistence on browers if the user hits a page-reload.
There are many ways to workaround this issue, for example WebStorage API (HTML5).

Comment: Thank you. I'll be use localStorage :)